# AVR assembly: create binary representation of RJMP

Tags: assembly, binary, arduino, hex, avr

I'm currently teaching myself assembly language by building an assembler for the Arduino Uno. However, I am struggling with converting RJMP to binary.

From the [amtel](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_RJMP.html) documents, RJMP is represented in binary as `1100 kkkk kkkk kkkk` where `k` is the relative address to jump to.

Assembling the following code:

```
check_press_loop: 
    sbis PIND, 2 
    rjmp check_press_loop
```

And disassembling I get:

```
10: fe cf           rjmp    .-4         ;  0xe
```

I understand why the relative jump is -4 bytes, what I don't understand is how this is represented by the hex `fc ef`. Swapping the order due to the "little endian" byte order (`cf fe`) gives a binary value of `0b1100111111111110`. Removing the instruction (`1100`) part of the binary value, how does `111111111110` represent -4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully you know that `111111111110` is -2 when interpreted as a twos-complement signed integer. The reason why -2 is used here is because `check_press_loop` is two 16-bit words back from the end the RJMP instruction.  Since AVR instructions are always word aligned there's no reason for RJMP instruction to be able to encode a jump offset measured in bytes. The processor isn't capable of executing an instruction at an odd byte address in program memory, the PC register isn't capable of holding such an address.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks very much for the explanation. Yes I had calculated the twos complement as -2 but was thrown by the disassembler's value of - 4!

Answer (score -1):

Try to jump 0x1234 :) to see where the nibbles are

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer, copy-paste it as a comment, then delete this answer (and you will get your lost reputation back!).